# Skype for Business meeting recording ios

Tags: ios, skype, skype-for-business, videochat

I am able to run the [demo banking app](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-ios-app-sdk-samples/tree/master/BankingAppObjectiveC) by Microsoft from github

By any chance can we record ongoing meeting in skype for business using their SDK or do we have any other third party libraries for recording video calls in ios.